# Creating directories in Bash Scripting with given string names

Tags: bash, shell

I am learning Bash. I have a question on Bash Scripting. How to receive a list of strings, creates directories with those strings as names, and print out a “report” in this format:

```
created directories:
=========
…. (names of directories that were created)
failed to create:
============
…. (names of directories you failed creating)?
```

Comment: Please format your question to make it more readable :)

Comment: Show us your attempt, otherwise it reads like you're asking us to do your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something like this:

```
success_files=''
failed_failes=''
while read file_name
do
  mkdir $file_name
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    success_files="$success_files $file_name"
  else
    failed_files="$failed_files $file_name"
  fi
done < ./file_names.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have shell prompt with me , but i hope below snippet would work .

```
    #!/usr/bin/bash
    filename="$1"
    while read -r line
    do
     mkdir $line
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
       createdDir="$createdDir"$'\n'"$line"
    else
       failedDir="$failedDir"$'\n'"$line"
    fi
       done < "$filename"
    echo "created directories: \n"
    echo $createdDir
    echo " failed to create: \n"
    echo $failedDir
```

How to use it ?

your-prompt>./script_name.sh file_name_with_dir_names